# In patch request fields which are not included inside allowedUpdates can also be updated

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

Suppose a model has fields a,b and c

and the patch for updating the model looks like this

```
router.patch('/entities/:id', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), async (req, res) => {
  const updates = Object.keys(req.body);
  const allowedUpdates = ['a', 'b'];
  const isValidOperation = updates.some((update) => allowedUpdates.includes(update));
  if (!isValidOperation) {
    res.status(400).send({ error: 'Invalid updates!' });
  }
  try {
      const entity = await Entity.findOne({ _id: req.params.id });
      const entityUpdated = await Entity.findByIdAndUpdate(entity,
        body,
        { new: true, runValidators: true });
      res.send(entityUpdated);
    } 
   catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  }
});
```

but in my api request (using postman) if I pass

```
{
    "c" : "some text",
}
```

C is not there in allowedUpdates.
Still C field gets updated and changes are shown in the backend data.

How can ensure that only the fields inside allowedUpdates are allowed to be updated and the rest throw the error?

Comment: You meant `isValidOperation = updates.every(…)` (not `some`), although I can't see how a request that updates *only* `c` would pass the test.

Comment: `Entity.findByIdAndUpdate` is weird. Shouldn't that be something like `Entity.updateAndSave`? The `findById` part is done in the previous line already. Also there's a stray `else` statement in your code with no matching `if` - please post your actual code.

Comment: I have tried update.every(...) the problem with that is even if you want to update just one field you have to enter all fields for that, with update.some(...) you can enter only some of them or all of them and get it to work

Comment: regarding the extra else i removed it because the corresponding was checking for another condition which is not useful to this question.

Comment: No, you definitely want `every`. You are checking whether *all* the fields supposed to be updated (the keys in the request body) are valid to be updated. Not the other way round.

Comment: Yes it works! I thought update.every works in a different way. Thanks a lot.